# Exchange Rate API With Buy & Sell Rate Of Dollar?

Tags: currency, yahoo-api, forex

As you know Buy & Sell Rate of Dollar is different.
Suppose If you go to buy Dollar in your local currency you will be cost 1000 Local Currency, but when you go to sell 100 Dollar you will get 900 in local curency.

So I want Buy Rate of Dollar which is usually higher.

I have used yahoo Finance Exchange rate service to get the exchange rate , but gives sell rate.
Do you know any configuration or any other API which gives this facility ?
I can also consider buying an API with moderate fee...

Thanks in advance !! :)

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: THIS IS NOT INTENDED AS A PROMOTION OF ANY SERVICE OR WEBSITE.**

Take a look at this sample feed from XE:

[XE Same Feed for USD](http://www.xe.com/datafeed/samples/sample-xml-usd.xml)

There are two fields in the Xml - "crate" and "cinverse" that provide the forward and reverse rates. The feed is reliable and as near up to date as possible. Not sure if their subscription rates are within your budget though.

[XE Data Feed subscription -- landing page](http://www.xe.com/datafeed/)

Comment: Hello Sir,  I am not looking for currency inverse !!
I am looking for Buy rate , this is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Every currency has a bid and offer rate, usually to reflect the cost of providing liquidity, plus a margin. The spreads between bid and offer increase the lower the amount, i.e. from wholesale to retail FX and by competitive pricing between currency brokers for different volumes.

Therefore the price to exchange 1mio USD will be a lot different to the price to exchange 100k USD or the price to exchange 10K USD or the price to exchange 1k USD or the price to exchange 100 USD.

There are a lot of currency brokers out there. Good ones for API are [interactive brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com), or [FXCM](http://www.fxcm.com).